# why is only the last item is showing and not all of them

Tags: javascript

I am using the code below to call a php page that displays all the products and then parse them and display them on the string. This was working fine last week displaying all the results however now it has seem to have broken and only displays the last results from the database and after several days and painful hour staring at my screen i am starting to go mad and could do with some help.

```
function display(results) {
    article = document.getElementById("homeArticle");
    item = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){ 
        var item = results[i];

        var name = item.P_NAME;
        var description = item.P_DESCRIPTION;
        var price = item.P_PRICE;
            // next I add to the string that we want to place on the page
        item = '<section id="homePageSection"> <p>Name:' + name + '</p><p>Description:' + description + '</p><p>Price:' + price + '</p></section>';
    };
    article.innerHTML = item;
}


function getItems() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var results = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        display(results.rows);
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "displayData.php");
    xhr.send();
}

window.addEventListener("load", getItems);
```

if anyone could have any pointers that would help massively thank you!

Comment: `item = '<section` overwrites `item` on each iteration... flawed logic.

Comment: Because you're overwriting the `item` variable each time through the loop. You need to concatenate it with `+=` instead of ovwriting with `=`.

Comment: i have tried using item `+=` but this didnt work all i got was `[object Object]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed two variables. One that you use to build up the html string and one to hold each item from the results array.

Change your code to this:

```
function display(results) {
    article = document.getElementById("homeArticle");
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){ 
        var item = results[i];

        var name = item.P_NAME;
        var description = item.P_DESCRIPTION;
        var price = item.P_PRICE;
            // next I add to the string that we want to place on the page
        html += '<section id="homePageSection"> <p>Name:' + name + '</p><p>Description:' + description + '</p><p>Price:' + price + '</p></section>';
    };
    article.innerHTML = html;
}
```

That way you will append the html strings rather than overwrite the prior one.

Also consider making sure that each html element has a unique id, you could do this by appending i to the id e.g.

```
html += '<section id="homePageSection-'+i+'"> <p>Name:' + name + '</p><p>Description:' + description + '</p><p>Price:' + price + '</p></section>';
```

Comment: i have tried using the `+=` but i am getting `[object, Object]` and the final result rather than all the results

Comment: Try steping through with a debugger to make sure that item is what you think it is.

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect that you were also overwriting the html string you were building at the top of your loop as well.

Comment: i have done this, and it is what i want it to be, im so confused as `[object, Object]` is when im not putting a string into a string but i dont get why its doing that for all but the last one and putting the last one on my screen

Comment: See my most recent change to my answer

Comment: 'item' is the javascript object that you get out of the array. 'html' is a string variable that you concatenate with in each iteration.

Comment: You needed two variables. One that you use to build up the html string and one to hold each member of the results array.

Comment: okay brilliant thank you!! I see where i was confusing the system now! Thank you so much!

Comment: I will do when the timer runs out in 2 minutes, i have been trying but it keeps telling me to wait for a certain amount of time! Thank you @bhspencer

Comment: Not going to downvote it, but keeping duplicate IDs is a **terrible practice**...

Comment: @Shomz would you recommend declaring all the vars at the start of the function scope? If so what advantage does that provide in this case. I am happy to change my answer.

Comment: No, no, just this: `id="homePageSection"`, was talking about the end HTML markup, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Agreed. I was just using the posters original html. This issue of how to give elements unique ids seemed to be outside of the scope of the original question.  But I do agree it is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Concat the `item` string, and don't use duplicate IDs, but classes instead:

```
item += '<section class="homePageSection"> <p>Name:' + name + '</p><p>Description:' + description + '</p><p>Price:' + price + '</p></section>';
```

What you were doing is overwriting `item` on each iteration, which I why you only get the last one.

---

UPDATE

Forgot to provide the code for that last sentence I wrote. To avoid overwriting it, either use a different variable (as in the other answer), or simply assign the values directly without creating unnecessary variables, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){ 
    item += '<section class="homePageSection"> <p>Name:' + 
            results[i].P_NAME + 
            '</p><p>Description:' + 
            results[i].P_DESCRIPTION + 
            '</p><p>Price:' + 
            results[i].P_PRICE + 
            '</p></section>';
}
```

Comment: @TomFenech, `item`'s properties are assigned, not the object itself.

Comment: That's obviously used for easier handling/delegating properties to variables `name`, `description` and `price`... Nothing is affected by destroying the original object, look: http://jsfiddle.net/yb36vuv8/ Reusing a variable is fairly common in places where performance matters a lot (not here, of course), just saying it's not a bad thing, and it poses no issues here.

Comment: But it effectively undoes the `item += '<section>'` that happens at the end of the loop from the previous time. So the problem still isn't solved and actually this causes the final concatenation of the string to look even worse than before since `[object Object]` shows up at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @Pluto, totally missed that. thanks! Added the code to support what I said originally.

Comment: @TomFenech, sorry, I completely forgot explaining the issue as soon as I wrote the `What you were doing is...` part. :)